# Create an ISODate with pyMongo

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x, pymongo, isodate

I've been trying to find a way to create an ISODate object whith pyMongo client, but without any success so far.

I use http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pymongo3 client, which is the only serious one available in Python 3 for now, but the problem doesn't seem to come from this specific pymongo version.

I'd like to know if any of you has found a solution to use this MongoDB object type from a pymongo client... thanks for your help !

Comment: if you need to convert a date other than "now" , you may also want to add timezone info to your datetime , before getting the utc value

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You just need to store an instance of datetime.datetime.

Inserting from the python shell:

```
>>> c.test.test.insert({'date': datetime.datetime.utcnow()})
ObjectId('4e8b388367d5bd2de0000000')
>>> c.test.test.find_one()
{u'date': datetime.datetime(2011, 10, 4, 16, 46, 59, 786000), u'_id': ObjectId('4e8b388367d5bd2de0000000')}
```

Querying in the mongo shell:

```
> db.test.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4e8b388367d5bd2de0000000"),
    "date" : ISODate("2011-10-04T16:46:59.786Z")
}
```

Comment: Does not seem to work, the stored data is a string. "timestamp" : "Wed Oct 05 2011 09:56:02 GMT+0200 (CET)",

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using?

Comment: Also, ISODate isn't a BSON type. That's just the way a BSON Datetime is represented in the shell. In PyMongo it's represented as an instance of datetime.datetime. http://bsonspec.org/#/specification

Comment: My MongoDB was < 1.7, once upgraded it works fine when I push datetime.datetime instances.

Comment: so easy. searched for this everywhere. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 15):

For those who are wondering how to create ISODate from timestamp:

```
ts = time.time()
isodate = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts, None)
```

This will create `datetime` object with no timezone. When inserted to MongoDB it will get converted to proper `ISODate()`.

Also, I strongly recommend looking at [Python TimeTransitionsImage](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeTransitionsImage). Note that `tuple` here is *named tuple* (equivalent to struct in C). And also note that tuple fields are not the same as in C counterparts, even though the naming is the same (for instance, tm_wday starts with Monday and not Sunday).

Comment: `fromtimestamp()` create a naive datetime object that represents time in the local timezone of your server: it is not what you want in most cases. You should use `datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts)` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Actually that does not work either. When you try to use either utcfromtimestamp or fromtimestamp, the program errors out saying that it needs a float. Just parse the string into a date time object and use that directly in the Mongodb. filter

```
from_dt = datetime.strptime('2018-04-01','%Y-%m-%d')
#from_dts = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(from_dt)
to_dt = datetime.strptime('2018-04-30','%Y-%m-%d')
#to_dts = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(to_dt)
filterCondition = { 
    "LastLogin" : { "$lte" : to_dt},
    "LastLogin" : { "$gte" : from_dt}
}
```

And then

```
db[(colName)].find({ "<colName>" : filterCondition })
```

Would work...

Answer (score 1):

```
result = db.objects.insert_one(
   {"last_modified": datetime.datetime.utcnow()})
```

Here utc stands for Universal Time Coordinates.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You could make this a better answer by adding some explanation of what the code is doing

Answer (score 0):

For create a document with specific date, for example 03/10/1999, run this:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from pymongo import MongoClient

db = MongoClient().db_name

date = datetime(1999, 03, 10)
db.collection.insert_one({'date': date})
```