# Python, Mongodb and timestamp

Tags: python, mongodb, database

I 'm doing a google API flights with Python, and put the timestamp , and now I saw that as the JSON API that generates is too large, serious good use mongoDB to the database and store.
But I'm a little lost as to place the timestamp at mongoDB and make these data is stored there.
Could someone give me a quick explanation about this and the " stepping stones " ( Where shall I begin , etc.) ?

Thank you: D

Answer (score 3):

Some quick googling reveals you can just use python's `datetime` module. Take a look [at this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651064/create-an-isodate-with-pymongo)

Also here's an example from the [PyMongo tutorial](https://api.mongodb.org/python/2.0/tutorial.html):

```
import datetime
post = {"author": "Mike",
        "text": "My first blog post!",
        "tags": ["mongodb", "python", "pymongo"],
        "date": datetime.datetime.utcnow()}

posts = db.posts
posts.insert(post)
```