# What format should I use to store timestamp in JSON for mongodb queries used in nodejs?

Tags: python, json, node.js, mongodb, isodate

I am currently using python to preprocess my data into JSON and insert my data into the collection via nodejs: `collection.insert(data, {safe:true}, function(err, result) {});`  My queries will be executed using nodejs as well.

I previously used python `datetime.datetime` to format my timestamps, and this is how my JSON is structured:

```
[{
   "timestamp" : "2016-08-02 20:30:02",
   "detail" : blah blah blah
  },{
   "timestamp" : "2016-08-02 20:33:23",
   "detail" : blah blah blah
  },
  ...
 ]
```

I was trying to query based on the timestamp, and according to a lot of posts such as this [Create an ISODate with pyMongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651064/create-an-isodate-with-pymongo), I am supposed to use `ISODate` for my query. So one of my attempts is:

```
  collection.findOne({ timestamp: new ISODate("2016-08-02T20:33:23.786Z")})
```

This one says that ISODate is undefined. So based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8848314/isodate-is-not-defined) I changed my query to:

```
  collection.findOne({ timestamp: new Date("2016-08-02T20:33:23.786Z")})
```

This one says record not found. How should I store my timestamps into JSON? Is `new Date("2016-08-02T20:33:23.786Z")` the right way to retrieve my instance? Also, when mongodb query timestamps, will it look at exact hours and minutes as well? I want to find the exact year, month, day, hour, minute and second just like how my timestamp is stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778428/best-way-to-store-date-time-in-mongodb) suggests that the best way is to use the JavaScript `Date` (constructed also via `ISODate`), which is native to Mongo. Digging into the [BSON documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#document-bson-type-date) it further clarifies the internal values:

> BSON Date is a 64-bit integer that represents the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch (Jan 1, 1970). This results in a representable date range of about 290 million years into the past and future.

So the short answer is: no matter which language you store it from, just store that 64bit integer number of milliseconds, which you will be able to read natively. I would expect that value to be in UTC, both written and read.

The [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999726/how-can-i-convert-a-datetime-object-to-milliseconds-since-epoch-unix-time-in-p) also tells you how to convert your python `datetime` object to milliseconds since epoch.