# How to insert datetime string into Mongodb as ISODate using pymongo

Tags: python, pymongo

How to insert datetime string like this `"2017-10-13T10:53:53.000Z"` into mongo db as ISODate? 
I get a string in mongodb when I insert:
 `datetime.strptime("2017-10-13T10:53:53.000Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z")`

Comment: Take a look: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/shell-types/ and https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Date/

Comment: You can go [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7651332/18036318) to find a solution that worked for me

Comment: A solution that worked for me : [on this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7651332/18036318)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This works for me:

```
from pymongo.mongo_client import MongoClient
import datetime

d = datetime.datetime.strptime("2017-10-13T10:53:53.000Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z")

with MongoClient() as mongo:
    db = mongo.get_database("test")
    db['dates'].insert({"date" : d})
```

Check in mongo:

```
> use test
switched to db test
> db.dates.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("589307d7cfd6c908d4b677d6"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-10-13T10:53:53Z")
}
```

**UPDATE**: As commented, if you get a "time data does not match format" error, try a more general format string such as: `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ`

Comment: I got a "time data does not match format", and had to change slightly the format string to: "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ"

Comment: It didn't work even changing to @Mirko format , "ValueError: time data '1970-01-18 20:15:07.234807' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'"

Comment: @Sohail, for that value the format would be `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"`  (Note that your value does not include the `T` separating the date from the time, nor the trailing `Z`. Hence these need to be removed from the format string.

Comment: python **datetime** object has **isoformat** method, e.g. `datetime.datetime.now().toisoformat()` is enough for current datetime as iso format

Comment: I tested `datetime.datetime.now().toisoformat()` and found `datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()` works in python 3.8. Maybe syntax changed?

Answer (score 3):

use `dateutil`
`dateutil.parser.parse("2017-10-13T10:53:53.000Z")`
will return `datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 13, 10, 53, 53, tzinfo=tzutc())`