# TypeError: Object of type 'datetime' is not JSON serializable, python

Tags: python, mongodb, datetime

I am trying to write date-time to MongoDB from python.

```
    time_second = ('{0}-{1}-{2} {3}:{4}:{5}.{6}{7}'.format(t_year, t_month, t_day, t_hour, t_minute, t_second, t_ms, t_us))
    date = datetime.strptime(time_second, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
    date_json = json.dumps(date)
```

I am getting the TypeError:

Comment: As the error message says, you cannot have a datetime object in json file.

Comment: Unless this is just a really strange example... it'd be a lot easier to create `date` directly with `datetime(t_year, ...)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to overcome "datetime.datetime not JSON serializable"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875770/how-to-overcome-datetime-datetime-not-json-serializable)

Comment: I need date time in the above mentioned format only, so that my other application can read it from MongoDB.

Comment: I found an suitable answer here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41999094/how-to-insert-datetime-string-into-mongodb-as-isodate-using-pymongo/41999637