# PyMongo - Python List to MongoDB datatype conversion

Tags: python, mongodb, type-conversion, pymongo, string-to-datetime

I am getting json response in string format from requests as below:

```
results = requests.request("POST", url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=header).json()['product']
```

Sample output:
**print(results)** - object type = <class '**list**'>

```
[
{
 'id': '123456',
 'product': 'XYZ',
 'exp_date': '03/01/2020',
 'amount': '30.5',
 'qty': '1'
},
{
 'id': '789012',
 'product': 'ABC',
 'exp_date': '04/15/2020',
 'amount': '22.57',
 'qty': '3'
},
{
 'id': '56789',
 'product': 'AAA',
 'exp_date': '03/29/2020',
 'amount': '',
 'qty': ' '
}
]
```

Need to convert all of these fields to specific datatype first and then insert into MongoDB as documents.

1. exp_date to **date/time**
2. amount to **float()**
3. qty to **int()**

What is the efficient way to do the datatype conversion ?

Was thinking if it's possible something like below, also need to know if there's any empty, null or blank string values, then how to replace it with some default value while during datatype conversion ?

```
new_result = []
for i in enumerate(results):
    i[exp_date] = datetime.strptime(i[exp_date],'%m/%d%Y').replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)                         #check for empty/null/blank values and replace with default date
    new_result.append(i[exp_date])

for i in enumerate(results):
    i[amount] = float(i[amount])   #check for empty/null/blank values and replace with 0.00
    new_result.append(i[amount])

for i in enumerate(results):
    i[qty] = int(i[qty])           #check for empty/null/blank values and replace with 0
    new_result.append(i[qty])
```

**db.collection.insert_many(new_result)**

new list output should look like: **print(new_result)**

```
[
{
 "id": "123456",
 "product": "XYZ",
 "exp_date": 2020-03-01 00:00:00,
 "amount": 30.5,
 "qty": 1
},
{
 "id": "789012",
 "product": "ABC",
 "exp_date": 2020-04-15 00:00:00,
 "amount": 22.57,
 "qty": 3
},
{
 "id": "56789",
 "product": "AAA",
 "exp_date": 2020-03-29 00:00:00,
 "amount": 0.0,
 "qty": 0
}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```py
import datetime

input_lst = [
{
 "id": "123456",
 "product": "XYZ",
 "exp_date": "03/01/2020",
 "amount": "30.5",
 "qty": "1"
},
{
 "id": "789012",
 "product": "ABC",
 "exp_date": "04/15/2020",
 "amount": "22.57",
 "qty": "3"
},
{
 "id": "56789",
 "product": "AAA",
 "exp_date": "03/29/2020",
 "amount": "",
 "qty": " "
}
]

output_lst = []


for dct in input_lst:
    tmp_dct = dct.copy()
    # amount - float, qty - int4
    try:
        tmp_dct['amount'] = float(dct['amount'])
    except:
        pass

    try:
        tmp_dct['qty'] = int(dct['qty'])
    except:
        pass

    try:
        tmp_dct['exp_date'] = datetime.datetime.strptime(tmp_dct['exp_date'],'%m/%d/%Y').replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)                         #check for empty/null/blank values and replace with default date
        output_lst.append(tmp_dct)
    except:
        pass


print(output_lst)
```

This is more efficient because you are only looping once.

Comment: ok. also, how to check for empty/blank/space in strings (amount, date, qty) and defaulting them while doing type conversion?

Comment: It's actually a list of tuples. Hence, giving error:- AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'copy'. Please suggest

Comment: Please change this in your question, because currently it is wrong. Please provide a sample input.

Comment: BTW, if you have a tuple like: (title=1), or something like that, you can access the value of title with: tuple_var_name.title

Comment: changed the sample input i.e. replaced " " double quotes with single (' ' ) quotes. Actually, the API response also has a root_element ('product') defined and which I updated as well in the request (post) response.

Comment: I made some changes below and it worked:                                                                              

output_lst = []                                                                                                                 
tmp_dct = dct.copy()
for i in enumerate(input_lst):                                                                                     
     tmp_dct[0]['amount'] = float(i[0]['amount'])
     tmp_dct[0]['qty'] = int(i[0]['qty'])
     output_lst.append(tmp_dct)
print(output_lst)

Thank you !!

Comment: Now the next challenge am facing is that the resulting output is a list (see below), with extra square [ ] brackets and different representation of date/time format: [ [ 
{
 'id': '123456',
 'product': 'XYZ',
 'exp_date': datetime.datetime(2020,03,01,0,0),
 'amount': 30.5,
 'qty': 1
} ] ]  .Due to this, it cannot insert this output to MongoDB as documents using insert_many() as it's giving this error :- "TypeError: document must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, bson.raw_bson.RawBSONDocument, or a type that inherits from collections.MutableMapping"

Comment: You could always insert the date, for example, "9/10/2020", and then convert it when you get the output (this could be part of the API).

Comment: actually, want to store date in iso format only while inserting into mongodb

Comment: Maybe try looking at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41999094/how-to-insert-datetime-string-into-mongodb-as-isodate-using-pymongo

Comment: ok, it works and may work fine when you want to insert just few fields including this date field. However, am trying to do bulk insert with lot many fields - so that I can load all the converted ISO date fields into MongoDB using insert_many() at one go. Also, even if I get these ISO date formatted fields stored as "strings" in mongodb, but still later want to avoid doing update_many() to the entire collection doing this conversion. Hence, looking for a way by which our output_lst above, can be directly inserted in bulk in Mongodb.

Comment: You make be out of luck. :( :(