# MongoDB Not saving specific datetime

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am using pymongo to save a datetime of the insertion of a document in a mongo collection here with the insert function:

```
cur_article['time'] = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

def insert(self, collection, doc):
    collection = self.get_db_instance(collection)
    collection.replace_one({'_id':doc['_id']} , doc, upsert=True)
    return True
```

For some reason though after insertion the datetimes only show up to the date for some not a whole timestamp. I am trying to find why as I would like a specific time tag.
[image: dbreturn]

Comment: Post your output as text, not as an image.

Comment: Maybe duplicate or might help not sure https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651064/create-an-isodate-with-pymongo